# unable to get file linecount of files in nifi

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I will be getting csv files (daily once around 10-12 csv files ) and using nifi we need to get the linecount of all csv files.

I have done this 
getfile -> counttext -> replacetext (in replace text i have replaced it with below value)
[image]

now i am getting output as 12 files and each file has linecount of that files now how to add those numbers in nifi

sample output files 
file1:- 40
file2:- 35
file3:- 55
here i need to get one file where my value should be sum of all numbers in all files 
ex:- 130 (as per above data)

Comment: Possible to mergecontent before counting lines.

Comment: you could as well use a counter and add up the linecount, and read/reset programmatically

Answer (score 1):

You can use combination of `getfile -> CountText -> ReplaceText -> mergeContent->QueryRecord` to get sum of all counts as flowfile by running a simple sql query.

After your replaceText processor as mergeContent processor with two settings :

`Minimum Number of Entries= <set this to minimum number of files you expect i.e. 10 or 12` 
`Demarcator= Shift + Enter for newline character`

[image]

Add `QueryReecord` processor with CSVREADER and CSVRECORDSETWRITE controller service.

[image]

You can use below avro schema as 'schema.text' in both controller service

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "cnt",
      "type": "long"
    }
  ]
}
```